# Setting Imageview as the header of tableview in xcode storyboard?

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I am trying to set an image as the header of a tableview. Below the image should be a prototype cell for displaying the info about the image.
I tried using the storyboard but i am erratic results.

Basically i want the layout it has on the pic i've attached

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'erratic results'. Can you post a screenshot of the result or the full error log?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/gIbk7Wq

Whatever i do i can't get the prototype cells in place below the image.When i add prototype cells they are nearly at the bottom of the screen. When i try to re-align them they get overlaid on top of the image.

Comment: or i get something like this where the tableview extends fully upto the top and i can't resize the table view or extend the image. http://i.imgur.com/edUp3Xq.png